# GSON - Ignore parsing exception

Tags: gson

Is there any way to force Gson to ignore any sort of parsing exception (just skip that field ) ?

Comment: What exception are you trying to ignore?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the field you are looking for, you COULD just not serialize that object. For example:

```
    public class test{

    String somString;
    Map<String,String> thisValueThrowsTheError;
    Int somInt;
}
```

If you wanted to just IGNORE the Map object, you could do that like this:

```
    public class test{

    String somString;

    @SerializeName("NOTAVALIDJSONOBJECTNAME")
    Map<String,String> thisValueThrowsTheError;
    Int somInt;
}
```

Gson won't see a name for that Map and it will skip that object.

Alternately (and ultimately the better solution) is just use a Deserializer to fix the issue that you have correctly. See this post as an example of a deserializer:

[Gson deserialization - Trying to parse a JSON to an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296427/gson-deserialization-trying-to-parse-a-json-to-an-object/9947726#9947726)